# Ionic: create APKs with different package names for debug and release build

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3

Is it possible to build Ionic Android apps with different package names?

Example:

- `com.example.myapp` for release version
- `com.example.myapp.debug` for debug version

Maybe there is a hook anywhere where to trigger a gulp task to manipulate config.xml (`<widget id="…">`)

Why I need this?

- Debug and Release versions access different backend resources
- I have a sharedUserId which must be different between debug and release because it is connected to the certificate used for signing.
- I need sharedUserId because the Ionic app is reading data from another app installed on the same device. They are signed with same certificate and use the same sharedUserId so access can be granted.
- Need a "playground" app for tests, debugging, ... and a productive app to verify production use. Don't want to buy different devices for this.

Comment: Why you need this? use case?

Comment: You could do a post build step in your package.json that would rename the package.  Call a build:debug which executes the normal build, then a postbuild:debug to rename the package.